# MySql Combine column into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have two tables

table 1

```
id | name | Description
---+------+------------
1  | A    |  123
2  | B    |  456
3  | C    |  789
```

table 2

```
id | price  |
---+--------+
1  | 12     |  
2  | 11     |  
3  | 13     |
```

I want to put description into table2

```
id | price  | Description
---+--------+------------
1  | 12     |  123
2  | 11     |  456
3  | 13     |  789
```

Comment: so what did you try so far to achieve this?

Comment: basic `select ... from A inner join B on ...`. It seems that you need to study a bit of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

an `INNER JOIN` will suffice your needs,

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.Price, a.Description
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cbb0/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "put" the description column into table2 without editing your schema, you can however use a join to get a resulting table to satisfy your needs.

`SELECT id, price, Description FROM table2 NATURAL JOIN table1`